# Can I show headings levels as letters rather than numbers?

Tags: html, css

I would like to shown some headings in HTML as letters rather than numbers.

For example, if I have the following HTML description:

```
<h1>the first chapter</h1> 
<h2>the first sub-chapter</h2>
<h1>the second chapter</h1>
```

I see:

```
1 the first chapter
1.1 the first sub-chapter
2 the second chapter
```

Is it possible (through using CSS for example), to have something like:

```
A the first chapter
A.1 the first sub-chapter
B the second chapter
```

Comment: I don't understand how you get the first output you showed. Where do the numbers come from? Then, it's not clear what you're asking for. You want `A` and `B` prepended to your headings? By what algorithm? It seems completely arbitrary. Please revise to be more clear.

Comment: There must be some code that creates those numberings please could you add it to your question.

Comment: Header elements (`<h1>`) do not produce the numbered output you describe, only ordered lists do or by using CSS counters. This question needs more detail or revisions by the OP to be answerable beyond a guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code must be using CSS counters I think to achieve the initial result you showed.

You can change how they are displayed by using the second parameter in CSS counter(). You are looking for upper-alpha.

Here is an example (your given HTML with a couple more h2s to show them working.

```css
body {
  counter-reset: h1;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  counter-reset: h2;
  counter-increment: h1;
}

h1::before {
  content: counter(h1, upper-alpha) ' ';
}

h2 {
  counter-increment: h2;
}

h2::before {
  content: counter(h1, upper-alpha) '.' counter(h2) ' ';
}
```

```html
<h1>the first chapter</h1>
<h2>the first sub-chapter</h2>
<h2>the second sub-chapter</h2>
<h1>the second chapter</h1>
<h2>the first sub-chapter</h2>
<h2>the second sub-chapter</h2>
```